# Fork again when child terminates

Tags: c, fork

How do we keep forking when the child process terminates? When the kid terminates, my program is supposed to sleep for ten seconds and fork the child again. I used a do while loop with wait(0) as the condition like this.

```
do{
if (fork() == 0)
{
...
return 0;
}
}while(wait(0));
```

But, it does not wait for ten seconds before forking the child again.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71155404/edit) to include a proper [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Your loop as it is will terminate as soon as you get a status from a child.

You need to re-write it to something similar to:

```
for (;;) { // Infinite loop.
           // May need to change the condition depending on when
           // you want to stop the program
    if (fork() == 0)
    {
    ...
    return 0;
    }
    while(wait(0)); // may also want to check for wait's failure
    sleep(10);
}
```

Comment: you need to handle the error condition of `fork`

Comment: depending on the rest of the program the childprocess should most probably `exit` and not `return`